# Converting List<dynamic> to List<Object>: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list class called StoreList which is a list class with parameter List. StoreList variables are meant to be used with local storage package.

When I try to retrieve data from the local storage using the package, the package function returns type List. I want to convert that to List. How do I do that? My code is as follows:

```
  Future<StoreList> getStoresFromLocalStorage() async {
    var storeInit = await storesLS.getItem('stores');
    StoreList stores = StoreList();
    if (storeInit == null) {
      stores.stores = List<Store>.empty(growable: true);
    }
    else {
      print(storeInit.toString()); // Output is [{id: C1, name: Store1, api: 'https://.....']
      stores.stores = storeInit;   // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC STATEMENT
    }
    return stores;
  }
```

EDIT:- I checked the types of the variables and they are as follows:-

storeInit => List

stores.stores => List

storeInit[0/1/2....] => _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>

EDIT 2:- Following is the Structure of the StoreList class

```
class StoreList {
  List<Store> stores = [];

  toJSONEncodable() {
    return stores.map((store) {
      return store.toJSONEncodable();
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to loop over your storeInit items and build a Store object with the Store.fromJson constructor

```dart
stores.stores = storeInit.map((data) => Store.fromJson(data)).toList();
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. I have added some more information about the types, maybe that will help?

Comment: I've edited my answer based on the additional info of your question

Comment: The first command seems to retain the same List<dynamic> format. To answer the second, yes, I have created 2 classes. The first class is a "Store" class with a format just like what you have written. The second is the "StoreList" class which I have added as an edit to the question. The function in StoreList was just to implement local storage package.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to use your Store class. It should work now. Else, please copy/paste the error that you're having. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but your function apparently doesn't change the type from List<dynamic> to List<String> (and I don't know why tbh since it is logically sound). The error is the same one,  Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Store>'.

Comment: Please add this to your answer, since this was what worked:      storeInit.forEach((storeData) {
        stores.stores.add(Store.fromJson(storeData));
      });

Comment: Basically I just had to use the Json to Map converter for each list element in the dynamic list. Since my "dynamic" data was a JSON object (the return type of the Local Storage function). Your suggestion of using the class was what led me to it.

Comment: Awesome! I've removed all the garbage to just leave the working code.